# Functional equation for Hurwitz Zeta

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been studying Reimann's functional equation (symmetric form) for Zeta(s) and wondering if a similar functional equation has been derived for the Hurwitz Zeta function?

Comment: Do you mean this one?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Functional_equation

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific , that form only covers Zeta(s,a) with 0 < a < 1, but I'm looking for something that works with "a" up to 2.